# Google Drive resumable upload with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload files to Google Drive using [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) and [resumable upload type](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable).

I authenticate and get the upload URI successfully, but I ran into problems while sending the actual data. If the file contains only ASCII characters, the file is sent successfully to Drive, but in case of special characters (åäö) or binary file (such as PNG) the file gets corrupted. My guess would be that somewhere in the process the file is encoded to unicode in client side.

If I use "btoa()" to encode the raw data to base64 and add header "Content-Encoding: base64" to the data sending request, the file uploads fine. Using this method however increases the overhead for 33%, which is quite a lot when the planned upload size of files is 100MB to 1GB.

Here are some code examples:

Getting the resumable upload URI:

```
// Authentication is already done
var request = gapi.client.request({
    "path": DRIVE_API_PATH, // "/upload/drive/v2/files"
    "method": "POST",
    "params": {
        "uploadType": "resumable"
    },
    "headers": {
        "X-Upload-Content-Type": self.file.type,
        //"X-Upload-Content-Length": self.file.size
        // If this is uncommented, the upload fails because the file size is
        // different (corrupted file). Manually setting to the corrupted file
        // size doesn't give 400 Bad Request.
    },
    "body": {
        // self.file is the file object from <input type="file">
        "title": self.file.name, 
        "mimeType": self.file.type,
        "Content-Lenght": self.file.size,
    }
});
```

Sending the whole file in one go:

```
// I read the file using FileReader and readAsBinaryString
// body is the reader.result (or btoa(reader.result))
// and this code is ran after the file has been read
var request = gapi.client.request({
    "path": self.resumableUrl, // URI got from previous request
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
        //"Content-Encoding": "base64", // Uploading with base64 works
        "Content-Type": self.file.type
    },
    "body": body
});
```

Am I missing something? Is it possible to upload file in binary stream? I am new to uploading files in HTML and Javascript and I haven't found any examples using Google Javascript library with resumable upload. There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360824/google-drive-api-resumable-upload-in-javascript) in SO with no answers.

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? This is a Javascript library to achieve the resumable upload for Google Drive. https://github.com/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js

Comment: @Tanaike I'm using your javascript library but I'm getting an error 401 "Invalid Credential" from Google. In my use case my access token was granted on the Server side ahead of time, which I saved in a database. I then share the access token with the user to allow them to upload files directly onto google. Is this not allowed by Google?

Comment: @pinghsien422 First, I apologize that my library was not useful for your situation. And also, I apologize for my poor English skill. About your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike It's ok! I resolved the issue, it's because my access token has expired. May I ask you another question? When I upload file using your library, I want to set the file to "Anyone with Link can view", can I set this metadata during upload, or must I do it with a separate API call? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @pinghsien422 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, this is not your question. So, I cannot post an answer of your new question. I apologize for this. If you want an answer to your question, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike Below is the link to my question. Thank you very much for your support. I really appreciate it!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75753463/google-drive-resumable-upload-using-javascript-setting-permission-to-anyone-wit

Comment: @pinghsien422 Thank you for your response. Now, I posted an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob types are a hot topic for `XMLHttpRequest` implementations and they are not truly mature. I'd recommend you to stick with base64 encoding. Google's JavaScript client lib doesn't support resumable uploads because it's very unlikely that a client side browser app uploads very large files directly to Google Drive.

Comment: Interesting.  Is this still true?  [MDN added blob support to `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) in July 2017.  I have an app that generates simulation data in the browser, and would prefer the browser upload a zip file directly to drive for the end user.  I found this post after getting a `text/csv` resumable upload working from the browser.

Comment: I've managed to get a 62MB `text/csv` file of 1M rows, generated from a loop and formula in the browser, into Drive with the 2-part technique Jani mentions.  Haven't tried a zip file yet but will soon.

Comment: We are making a video site and we want to save our data to google drive. if we don't upload directly to google drive we will have to upload to our server first which is a really scary thing for us. So, there should be any way to upload large files directly.

Answer (score 0):

### What works

To upload a binary blob, use github/googleapi's [cors-upload-sample](https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample) or use [my gist fork, UploaderForGoogleDrive](https://gist.github.com/DrPaulBrewer/eaea4ad927389643e56ce566d4ed513e), which will grab `access_token` out of the gapi client for you.

Here is an ugly mixture of Promise and callback code that works for me. As a prerequisite, `gapi`,`UploaderForGoogleDrive`, `JSZip` need to be loaded via `<script>` tags.  The snippet also omits gapi initialization and the API secrets, which are also necessary.

```
function bigCSV(){  // makes a string for a 300k row CSV file
    const rows = new Array(300*1000).fill('').map((v,j)=>{
      return [j,2*j,j*j,Math.random(),Math.random()].join(',');
    });
    return rows.join("\n");
}

function bigZip(){  // makes a ZIP file blob, about 8MB
    const zip = new window.JSZip();
    zip.folder("A").file("big.csv", bigCSV());
    return zip.generateAsync({type:"blob", compression:"DEFLATE"});
    // returns Promise<blob>
}

function upload2(zipcontent){
   'use strict';
    const parent = 'root';
    const spaces = 'drive';
    const metadata = {
      name: 'testUpload2H.zip',
      mimeType: 'application/zip',
      parents: [parent]
    };
    const uploader = new window.UploaderForGoogleDrive({
      file: zipcontent,
      metadata: metadata,
      params: {
        spaces,
        fields: 'id,name,mimeType,md5Checksum,size'
      },
      onProgress: function(x){
         console.log("upload progress:",Math.floor(100*x.loaded/x.total));
      },
      onComplete: function(x){
        if (typeof(x)==='string') x = JSON.parse(x);
        // do something with the file metadata in x
        console.log("upload complete: ");
      },
      onError: function(e){ console.log("upload error: ",e); }
    });
    uploader.upload();
}

function uploadZipFile(){
    'use strict';
    (bigZip()
      .then(upload2)
    );
}
```

### What doesn't work

As of Nov 2017, uploading a binary blob with the `gapi.client.request` call is not going to work, because of an [issue where gapi removes the PUT payload](https://issuetracker.google.com/66142841)

I've also tried using base64 with `gapi`, which works. but deposits base64 files, not true binaries; and the fetch API in cors mode, which half-worked but produced CORS-related errors and response hiding, at least for me.