# Uploading to Google Drive - how to use a base64-encoded image or an image path

Tags: javascript, image, upload, google-drive-api, ngcordova

Fairly new to Javascript and still running into this problem after trying a lot of things:

I'm using http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/ to capture an image on the phone and can retrieve as either a base64-encoded image or as a path to the image location (file://storage/emulated/...jpg).

Next I'm using this to upload files to google drive: https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample

I've successfully uploaded a text file with the given example:

```
* @example
 * var content = new Blob(["Hello world"], {"type": "text/plain"});
 * var uploader = new MediaUploader({
 *   file: content,
 *   token: accessToken,
 *   onComplete: function(data) { ... }
 *   onError: function(data) { ... }
 * });
 * uploader.upload();
```

But when I upload an image, it cannot be viewed and I assume it is because I have encoded it wrong.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- using the base64-encoded imagedata directly
- creating a blob of image/jpeg type and putting the 64encoded imagedata inside
- appending "data:image/jpeg;base64," in front of the imagedata
- this person's suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27197907/5568940

Is it also possible to use a FileReader to read the image path into a File instead? I just can't figure out what exactly should go into the "file: content" part for an image for the above example code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload is expecting the raw image bytes.

Haven't tried this, but easiest approach is likely working with the image URL which you can resolve to a file (which is also a blob :)

Something like:

`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri, function(fileEntry) {
  var errorHandler = ...;
  fileEntry.file(function(file) {
    var uploader = new MediaUploader({
      file: file,
      token: accessToken,
      onComplete: function(data) { ... }
      onError: function(data) { ... }
    });
    uploader.upload();
  }, errorHandler);
});`

Comment: Thanks Steve! This looks like just what I need. As a side note, I'm encountering problems with window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(), but I think that's a separate issue.